# 20.04 clipboard inconsistancies causing prob in LibreOffice and OpenOffice

Tags: clipboard

I see that this has been around since 2010 but how to fix it. I tried Parcellite but it does nothing. xsel -bc (sp?) can clear clipboard but the first time I use it the prob starts again. Works fine using keyboard Ctl-c or v, but using mouse (tried different mouse also) right click choose copy: only **sometimes** resets contents of clipboard - on paste I am just as likely to get, correct stuff, previous stuff, or nothing. How to fix. I installed Apache OpenOffice via PlayOnLinux but it responds exactly the same way. I know it's an X bug but do I have to go to Win to do my word processing? I can test using LibreOffice or TextEditor as target - same result.

Comment: Hi, can you add links to where you found related bugs and information your mention? Have you tried to post an issue report there? It looks like if you need to provide more technical details, logs, etc. Developers might help you with that if they get aware of this bug. Good luck!

Comment: I could google and get them but they were mostly 2010 year  mentions and I hardly think it useful to try to open them. There has been a smattering of Ubuntu 14, 16, but, again, I would think Canonical would have gotten the message and fixed it. i3 was supposed to fix that but I tried it and it's a keyboard system - not for me, so uninstalled it.

Comment: @Mario The question is highly justified. The clipboard in mutter is broken since it was reworked, and while the situation has improved, it is not yet solved. There is one link in my answer to the follow-up bug. Actually, I am surprised no more people report here on this very visible clipboard failure.

Comment: Thanks, @vanadium, for clarifying my question. Haven't been familiar with that surprising bug.

Comment: @mario you may not be working a lot with LO: there the problem is very manifest. Or you overall do not copy/paste a lot ;) Or you are working with LTS 18.04, which does not have the bug (I think)

Comment: True, I'm working with LO only occasionally, and even then, most of the time, with keyboard shortcuts. Hence, my surprise. But, yes, that bug is critical. No question.

Answer (score 0):

In 20.04, the clipboard [indeed still is broken](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1268). However, the situation is much (really much) better if you use the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>/<kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>   rather than the mouse.

So we have to wait, lacking the necessary programing skills to step in ourselves.

Workarounds:

- Take the (good) habit of using the keyboard;
- Switch to a Wayland session instead: the issue does not exist there;
- Switch to the previous long-term release of Ubuntu, 18.04, where the bug does not yet exist;
- Move to another desktop environment.

Of course you can go to Windows, but there are alternatives.

Comment: Yes, windows... It seems that about every year I try Ubuntu and try hard to make it work for me, and then wind up falling back to windows. A week ago I started playing with 20.04 . Sad that , again, I am told to "make do and use the DOS3.11 method of keyboard". Yes, I can do that but it is a much slower method and after all, we use these things to save time, not to serve a company. No offense to Canonical whom i think has done great, but cheese. clipboard???????????????? in 2020?????????????

Comment: The issue indeed does not exist in Wayland. However Wayland does not like to show the applications either in the tray or on the side bar - last time delay was 3 min 50 seconds, and still no app tray.

Comment: I understand and agree with your frustration. Such clipboard issues should not be existing in the year 2020. However, I do not find click click with the mouse to be more efficient than Ctrl+C Ctrl+V. You also must be facing issues with configuration or the graphics card if running Wayland gives you trouble.